# .htaccess - hotlink prevention not working for other hosted domains

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer, hotlinking

This is probably a simple solution, but I have a hosting account and a primary domain associated with it. I also have other domains 'sub-hosted' on the same account. I setup hotlink prevention at the document root. However, it only works for the primary domain. The sub-hosted domains continue to allow hotlinking.

Here is the code I'm using. What modifications might be necessary to prevent hotlinking for the other domains on the same host? Thanks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?PRIMARY-DOMAIN.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?SUB-HOST1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?SUB-HOST2.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?SUB-HOST3.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://www.PRIMARY-DOMAIN.com/Images/Hotlink/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Images/Hotlink/
```

Comment: What is the document root of your subdomain ? Does it point to `/subdomain` folder?

Comment: In the document root, the subdomains point to folders with the same name.

Comment: Maybe I need site-specific .htaccess rules at each /subdomain folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the document root, the subdomains point to folders with the same name.

If these subdirectories also have their own `.htaccess` files that contain mod_rewrite directives then (by default) these directives will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (in the main domain). So, your "hotlinking" directives will never get processed.

You either need to enable mod_rewrite inheritance. However, this can come with caveats if you have other directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. And depends on whether you have Apache 2.2 or 2.4+

For example, on Apache 2.4, you can include the following directive in the parent `.htaccess` file to process the "hotlinking" directives *before* the directives in the subdomain's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

But note that this could break your site, depending on what other directives you have in the `.htaccess` file. mod_rewrite inheritance works by literally copying the directives in-place - this can be a problem if you are relying on the directory-prefix.

Or, you reproduce these hotlinking directives in the `.htaccess` files of each subdirectory/subdomain.

> ```
> RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://www.PRIMARY-DOMAIN.com/Images/Hotlink/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Images/Hotlink/
> ```

These directives are the wrong way round. The `RewriteRule` should be last.

Comment: To clarify, the subdomain folders do not have their own .htaccess files. $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] returns only "Apache". Not looking to break the site with IneritDownBefore. Lastly, the RewriteCond was intended to allow the hotlink image to display - an exception to hotlink images.

Comment: In that case, without looking at the server config, it's not obvious why this wouldn't work. The directives themselves are "OK". However, it could depend on how these "sub-hosted domains" have been implemented - for instance, it's possible that `AllowOverride` has been restricted to the "sub-hosted domains" document root. "the RewriteCond was intended to allow the hotlink image to display" - Right, I understand. However, the `RewriteCond` directive will still need to go before the `RewriteRule` for it to have any effect.

Comment: I'll reach out to my host and see if there are any restrictions in place that may prevent me from using an htaccess hotlink solution.

Comment: "htaccess hotlink solution" itself is probably not the problem. Being able to inherit mod_rewrite directives from a parent config that is above the DocumentRoot of the current host is more likely to be the problem. This is easy to test... set an environment variable in the parent config using both `SetEnv` (mod_env) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) - do you see one or other or both when accessing `sub-host.com`?

Comment: I emailed my host. Haven't heard back, but today - they're all working. So either the changes I made took some time to be recognized by the server, or they made changes behind the scenes and haven't explained it to me yet.